# Find joint distribution of minimum and maximum of iid random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

$(X_n)$ sequence of iid random variables with uniform distribution $U([0,1])$.
$m=\min(X_1,...X_n), M=\max(X_1,...X_n)$.

I want to find $f_{m,M}(s,t)$.

$$
\begin{split}
P(m<s,M<t)
 &= P(m<s)P(M<t)1_{m\ne M}+P(X_1<\min(s,t))1_{m=M} \\
 &= (1-(1-s))^nt^n1_{m \ne M}+\min(s,t)1_{m=M} \\
 &=((st)^n+s)1_{s<t}+((st)^n+t)1_{s \ge t}
\end{split}
$$

When I differentiate it, I get $f_{m,M}(s,t)=n^2t^{n-1}s^{n-1}$.

Is this okay? And does it mean that $M$ and $m$ are independent and $f_{m,M}(s,t)=f_m(s)f_M(t)$?

Comment: Interesting follow-up question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814215/pdf-and-cdf-of-the-ratio-of-the-max-to-min-of-an-iid-random-sample-a-quick-chec

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054665/321264

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For a sequence of $n$ iid *continuous* samples, $(X_i)_{n=1}^n$, the minimum is less than $s$ and maximum less than $t$ **iff** all samples are less than $t$ and at least one is less than $s$.

$$\begin{split}
\mathsf P(m\leqslant s, M\leqslant t) &=\mathsf P\Big(\big(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \{X_i\leqslant s\}\big)\cap\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}\big)\Big)
\\&= \mathsf P\Big(\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}\big)\setminus\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{s<X_i\}\big)\Big)
\\ &= \mathsf P\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}\big)-\mathsf P\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{s< X_i\leq t\}\big)
\\ &= \prod_{i=1}^n\mathsf P\{X_i\leqslant t\}-\prod_{i=1}^n\mathsf P\{s<X_i\leqslant t\}
\\ &= \big(\mathsf P\{X_i\leqslant t\}\big)^n-\big(\mathsf P\{s<X_i\leqslant t\}\big)^n
\\ & =\begin{cases} 0 &:& s<0 ~\vee~ t<0
\\ t^n-(t-s)^n & :& 0\leqslant s\leqslant t< 1 
\\ t^n &:& 0\leqslant t < \min (s,1)
\\ 1-(1-s)^n &:& 0\leqslant s< 1\leqslant  t
\\ 1 &:& 1\leqslant s ~\wedge~ 1\leqslant t 
\end{cases}
\\[2ex]f_{n,M}(s,t) &=\begin{cases} n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2} & :& 0\leqslant s\leqslant t< 1 
\\ 0 &:& \textsf{elsewhere} 
\end{cases} 
\end{split}$$

Comment: How can I do these when $X_i$ have continuous distributions?
$P(x \le t)=P(x < t)$, right?

Comment: I can use only the first part you wrote, right? And the density will be $nt^{n-1}-n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2}$?

Comment: Ah, right.  Then indeed, you just need the first and differentiate.

Comment: @GrahamKemp the last case $1\leq s$ and $1 \leq t$ should be $1$, right?

Comment: @DanielOrdoñez Good catch.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I already asked a similar question related to this question"https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573532/the-density-of-for-a-couple-of-random-variables". Would you please clarify how you moved from first equality to the second

Comment: @GrahamKemp Could you please clear up how you moved from the first equality to the second one in the above solution. I would be very grateful if you reply to my comment.

Comment: $A\cap B=A\smallsetminus B^\complement$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have an equation where on the left hand side you have a probability of an event - so a number - and on the right hand side you have probabilities multiplied with indicator functions - so a random variable. That's not okay.

Secondly, you are using the independence you want to show, when you say that $P[m<s,M<t,m<M]=P[m<s]P[M<t]$.

Hint on independence: What would you guess is the probability that $P[m>0.8,M<0.2]$? Why does this show that they are not independent?

There is one general trick for these kind of questions, namely $M<c$ if and only if $X_i < c$ for all $i$. Then use independence of the $X_i$ to compute $P[M<c]$. A similar trick is used for the min. Hint: Try the same thing as for the maximum, but use $P[A^c]=1-P[A]$.

Comment: "Secondly, you are using the independence you want to show, when you say that..." 
 
Am I? I used it for $m \ne M$ and I know that $X_i=M$ and $X_j=m$ are independent for $i \ne j$. I take the case where $i=j$ separately. That's why I used indicators (how should I do it without indicators, so that I don't have a random variable on the right side?)

Comment: "There is one general trick for these kind of questions, namely $M<c$ if and only if $Xi<c$ for all $i$. Then use independence of the $Xi$ to compute $P[M<c]$. A similar trick is used for the min. Hint: Try the same thing as for the maximum, but use $P[Ac]=1−P[A]$." - I think I did all of these in my solution.

Comment: What you should have written is

Comment: Regarding your first comment: Yes, you are. How else would you get that $P[m<s,M<t,m\neq M]=P[m<s] P[M<t]$? Please go, calculate $P[m>0.8,M<0.2]$ and compare it to $P[m>0.8]$ times $P[M<0.2]$. What I want to tell you is that they cannot be independent because the maximum must be at least as high as the minimum. But I guess Graham gave a 'no additional thinking required' answer, which is probably good for your homework points and the website in general but bad for your understanding. (Sorry for the last comment, I didn't know that pressing enter shoots a comment...)

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the definition of CDF the way you want. Just remember the negative sign on differentiating to find the PDF.

$$\begin{split}
P(m > s, M\leqslant t) &=P\Big(\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n \{X_i > s\}\big)\cap\big(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\leqslant t\}\big)\Big)
\\ &= \prod_{i=1}^n P(s<X_i\leqslant t)
\\ & =
\begin{cases} 
(t - s)^n & 0 \leqslant s \leqslant t < 1 \\
t^n & s < 0 < t \leqslant 1 
\\ (1 - s)^n & 0 < s < 1 < t
\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\ \\ f_{n,M}(s,t) &=
\begin{cases} n(n-1)(t-s)^{n-2} & 0\leqslant s\leqslant t < 1 
\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases} 
\end{split}$$