# joint PDF of max and min of $n$ iid standard uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $U_1, ... U_n$ be iid standard uniform variables.
Let $X = max(U_i)$ and $Y = min(U_i)$.
The goal is to compute the joint PDF of $X, Y$!

I have already computed the PDFs of $X$ and $Y$ separately.
But I am not sure if that is so useful because $X, Y$ are not independent (by definition $X \geq Y$) so it is not correct to just multiply the marginal PDFs of $X$ and $Y$.

I thought about starting from the CDF and taking advantage of the fact that all of the $U_i$'s are independent. So something like: $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = P(U_1, ...U_n \leq x, \text{at least one $U_i$ is less than }y)$ and you can already see the problem here -- I don't know how to express the relation for $Y$ in terms of all the $U_i$'s like that. when computing $Y$'s CDF, I did $1 - P(U_1 \geq y, ... U_n \geq y)$ and was able to take advantage of the independence of all the $U_i$'s there. But I'm not sure how to translate that to the joint PDF of $X, Y$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2631988/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054665/321264

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, on $A=\{0\le y<x\le 1\}$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(X\le x,Y\le y)&=\mathsf{P}(X\le x)-\mathsf{P}(Y>y,X\le x) \\
&=\mathsf{P}\left(\bigcap_{1\le i\le n}(U_i\le x)\right)-\mathsf{P}\left(\bigcap_{1\le i\le n}(y<U_i\le x)\right) \\
&=x^n-(x-y)^n.
\end{align}
Therefore, on $A$,
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{d^2}{dxdy}(x^n-(x-y)^n)=n(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have a question, though -- would you mind explaining the first and third equalities a little more? I am really not seeing how you arrived at the first one in particular (I'm not questioning if it's correct, I just do not follow!).

Comment: The event $\{X \le x\}$ can be partitioned into two disjoint events, based on whether $Y \le y$ or $Y > y$. The probability of $\{X \le x\}$ is therefore the sum of probabilities of these two smaller events.

Comment: @0k33 The third equality follows from independence and the fact that $\mathsf{P}(y<U_i\le x)=x-y$.

Comment: Thank you both so much! It's clear now!

Comment: @angryavian Hello! I apologise for bringing up such an old post, but I am trying to solve a similar problem to the OP's. Do you mind explaining your comment in greater detail? In particular, I do not quite understand how "the event $\{X \leq x\}$ can be partitioned into two disjoint events, based on whether $Y \leq y$ or $Y > y$", or rather, I am still not clear as to how the first equality is derived.

Comment: @EthanMark The event $\{X \le x\}$ is the disjoint union of the events $\{X \le x, Y \le y\}$ and $\{X \le x, Y > y\}$. In general $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Comment: @EthanMark The first equality is $P(A) = P(A \cup B) - P(B)$.

Comment: @EthanMark The statement "$\{X \le x\}$ is the disjoint union of the events $\{X \le x\} \cap \{Y \le y\}$ and $\{X \le x\} \cap \{Y > y\}$" holds for any random variables $X$ and $Y$, not just in this problem. Try to show that for any events $E_1$ and $E_2$ we have that $E_1 \cap E_2$ and $E_1 \cap E_2^c$ are disjoint events whose union is $E_1$.

Comment: Oh okay I think I see it now... It's simply the law of total probability isn't it. Since $E_2$ and $E^c_2$ form a partition then $(E_1 \cap E_2) \cup (E_1 \cap E^c_2) = E_1$?