# Calculating CDF of sum of variables

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Seems like I'm rather stuck on this issue, which should be pretty simple.
Say I have n i.i.d variables that distribute uniformly. Denote $X$ as their maximum, $Y$ as their minimum.
[I know that $_{,}(,)=(−1)(−)^{−2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037511/joint-pdf-of-max-and-min-of-n-iid-standard-uniform-random-variables), and I need to find $P(X+Y\leq z)$. It should be done by a double integral over the required domain, but I am afraid that even finding the domain gives me a hard time.
We require $0\leq y\leq x\leq 1 \wedge x+y\leq z$ and so it should be:
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{1}\int\limits_{y}^{z-y}(−1)(−)^{−2}dxdy=\frac{z^n}{2}
$$
or
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{z/2}\int\limits_{0}^{x}(−1)(−)^{−2}dydx + \int\limits_{z/2}^{z}\int\limits_{0}^{z-x}(−1)(−)^{−2}dydx = 1-\frac{1}{2}(2-z)^n
$$
Neither one of this is the right answer by simply checking for the condition that $0\leq P(X+Y\leq z) \leq 1$.
Yet I believe that I have minor issue in finding the right domain. I'd be thankful for any kind of help.

Thanks!

EDIT: U1…Un are taken from uniform distribution.

Comment: What is the distribution of your variables? You wrote that they distribute normally (so I assume you meant normal distribution), but the link you provided refers to uniform distribution.

Comment: Correct, thank! They are uniform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We already know that if $X$ is the maximum and $Y$ is the minimum, then the joint PDF is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = n(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}\cdot\textbf{1}_{0\leq y\leq x\leq 1}(x,y),$$
where $\textbf{1}_A(x)$ is the indicator function. We are interested in finding the CDF of $X+Y$ (in other words $P(X+Y\leq z)$). Notice that $0\leq X+Y\leq 2$. Let's consider 2 cases:

- $z\in [0,1)$: In this case our domain is $\{0\leq x\leq \frac{z}{2},0\leq y\leq x\}\cup\{\frac{z}{2}\leq x\leq z,0\leq y\leq z-x\}$. So
  $$\begin{split}P(X+Y\leq z)&=\int_0^\frac{z}{2}\int_0^xn(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}dy\ dx+\\
  &+\int_\frac{z}{2}^z\int_0^{z-x}n(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}dy\ dx,\end{split}$$
  which evaluates to $\frac{z^n}{2}$.
- $z\in[1,2]$: Now our domain is diffirent, because $x\leq 1$. So we need to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over $\{0\leq x\leq \frac{z}{2},0\leq y\leq x\}\cup\{\frac{z}{2}\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq z-x\}$. So
  $$\begin{split}P(X+Y\leq z)&=\int_0^\frac{z}{2}\int_0^xn(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}dy\ dx+\\
  &+\int_\frac{z}{2}^1\int_0^{z-x}n(n-1)(x-y)^{n-2}dy\ dx,\end{split}$$
  which evaluates to $1-\frac{(2-z)^n}{2}$
  In the end we get
  $$P(X+Y\leq z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  0, & z < 0\\
  \frac{z^n}{2},& z\in[0,1)\\
  1-\frac{(2-z)^n}{2},&z\in[1,2)\\
  1,& z\geq 2.
  \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! Do you think there’s a way to deduce this from basic probability (i.e. without integrals)?

Comment: Maybe there is, but I think that this is the easiest way to go about it. I'd be impressed if there's an easier way to prove this without integrals.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on how did you find the domain of integration please?

Comment: I mean, I drew the integration zone and it made sense. But is there a more analytic way to find this out? And to verify that the domain is indeed correct?

Comment: I think that drawing the area is your best bet. You simply need to 'swap' the axes and go from there.